# When does one use $asArray vs $asObject in Angularfire?

Tags: firebase, angularfire

It seems like there are many situations where one could choose whether to use `$asArray` or `$asObject`, in the same situation.  You could get away with using either.

I'm a bit of a code/js beginner, but when should one use $asArray vs. $asObject?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest version of angularfire `1.0.0` uses new $firebaseArray and $firebaseObject services that replace $asArray and $asObject when accessing collections or objects.

If you are using the latest version, you should convert $asObject and $asArray to the new services.

```
var arr = $firebase(new Firebase(URL)).$asArray;
var obj = $firebase(new Firebase(URL)).$asObject;
```

becomes

```
var arr = $firebaseArray(new Firebase(URL));
var obj = $firebaseObject(new Firebase(URL));
```

Additional information is available at [AngularFire Documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-addnewdata)

Answer (score 3):

You should utilize `$asObject` for objects (hashes of key/value pairs), such a user's profile, a book description, or a form post's details. Or, to quote [the guide](https://firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html):

> Objects are useful for storing key/value pairs, and singular records that are not used as a collection.

You should utilize `$asArray` for a collection, such as a list of users, books, or form posts.

To put it another way, if you will iterate it and utilize it in `ng-repeat`, it's probably a collection. If you will access properties by name, like `data.some_key` on it, it's probably an object.

Comment: What if there is a mix? Say a profile object, which has properties for name and such and a property that contains an array of addresses (say places where you have lived in your life)? How would you handle this?

Comment: Store the addresses in their own collection, access them using an array. Store the profile in an object. Don't nest your data, it'll make you sad.