# How to get the json array length from firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have a code that retrives a simple json array and i just want to loop

```
var ref = new Firebase("firebase object path");
var sync = $firebase(ref);
var result = sync.$asArray();
```

and then i can't get the json array length using "result.length" it just give a result of 0 length but not the exact value can anyone help me...?

Comment: What version of AngularFire are you using here? It looks like an old alpha release from years ago. Please, please update to something modern.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because it's not loaded yet. Looks like you're using an old verison of angularFire as `$asArray` is deprecated see: [When does one use $asArray vs $asObject in Angularfire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437224/when-does-one-use-asarray-vs-asobject-in-angularfire), https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/migration/09X-to-1XX.md

Once you've upgraded (if you can)

```
$firebaseArray(ref).$loaded().then(function(data){
    console.log(data.length)
});
```

I can't seem to find the docs for when `$asArray` was around but looking through the second link up there I think you can accomplish it like this:

```
sync.$asArray().$loaded().then(function(array) {
    console.log(array.length);
});
```

---

With a watch:

```
$scope.data = [];
sync.$asArray().$loaded().then(function (array) {
    $scope.data = array;
});
$scope.$watch('data', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log($scope.data.length);
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot for raplay... but when i make a change in my firebase object it doesn't update the length value or i have to refresh my page to see the change what shall i do....?

Comment: You'll have to wire up a value change event: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events or wire up a `.$watch`

Comment: is this the correct way of using .$watch  lo listen the array length change....sync.$asArray().$loaded().then(function(array) {
      $scope.len = array.length;
    });
    $scope.$watch($scope.len, function(newValue,oldValue) {
     $scope.len = $scope.len;
    });

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: The console reponse ... data is not defined.. i.e the data in .$watch

Comment: Whoops, supposed to be $scope.data.length