# Firebase JavaScript / AngularFire - How Do I Get the Last Added Property of an Watched Object?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have a Firebase object that looks like:

```
-notifications
    -1-1-2017 1:08:22 PM
        -message: 'test'
        -timestamp: 1483294112
    -1-1-2017 1:08:23 PM
        -message: 'two'
        -timestamp: 1483294113
    -1-1-2017 2:08:22 PM
        -message: 'three'
        -timestamp: 1483294473
```

I am constantly pushing new properties into the `notifications` object where the key is a datetime.

How do I get the latest property attached to the `notifications` object if I have a `$watch` that looks like the following?

```
var ref = new Firebase(firebaseConstants.url + 'notifications');
var sync = $firebase(ref);
$scope.notifications = sync.$asArray();
$scope.$watch('notifications', function(){
    ......
});
```

I would like to avoid running loops on `$scope.notifications` to find the difference between the old and new values.

Is there a built-in way with either the Firebase JS API or the AngularFire library to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems like you are using an outdated version of angularfire. My answer will be based on the newest version (2.2.0). However, all the features I will be using here have been available since 1.0.0 according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28896261/6162666

Since you asked for built-in way to do this, I'm not going to try giving an answer based solely on $scope.$watch. Angularfire objects and arrays have supported the $watch method for a long time now. You can simply call $watch on your $firebaseArray and it will tell you when new events occur.

Note that $watch is called on your $firebaseArray/$firebaseObject, and not on your $scope.

Having said all of that, if you converted your code to the newest version of angularfire, it would look something like this:

```
var ref = new Firebase(firebaseConstants.url + 'notifications');
var notifications = $firebaseArray(ref);
notifications.$watch(function(events){
   console.log(events); //Logs all the child_added events when new notifications are pushed
});
```

Comparatively, the example given in the [docs](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#watchcb-context) is the following:

```
var list = $firebaseArray(ref);

list.$watch(function(event) {
  console.log(event);
});

list.$remove("foo");
// logs { event: "child_removed", key: "foo" }

list.$add({ hello: "world" });
// logs { event: "child_added", key: "<new_id>", prevId: "<prev_id>" }
```

Later, you can call $destroy() to stop listening for changes.

I should point out that this will only show you the new ids as they are added, which seems to be exactly what you need.